# Total Yearly Expenditures for a Single Person in the USA

Tags: united-states, expenses, cost-cutting, spending

I recently calculated every single penny I spent in 2014 (literally *everything*). Let's round up and say the total came to $21,000. I would like to know where I stand in terms of spending. I was trying to collect some data to see how I compare, but I am having some trouble finding recent statistics. I am welcoming, of course, help to find such data, but I am also welcoming your opinions!

Since it may be relevant, I am a 26 year old male.

Comment: Data typically lags by a few years. Curious what you'd do with this data. You spent $21k, but did you save anything?

Comment: Its a meaningless number. What good is it for you?

Comment: Maybe you should be concentrating on what portion of the $21K was wasteful spending which could be eliminated or reduced.

Comment: As an aggregate total, probably not very useful. But if you see you are spending more than average on one particular thing, that may be a sign that this is an area where you could reduce expenses. Life if you discover that you are spending 25% more than average on electricity, maybe you are wasting energy and you should look into that. Also, I'd be most concerned about where I am spending a lot. Like if my mortgage is 30% of my income and gas for my car is 2%, it makes sense to spend a lot more time trying to reduce my mortgage payments than trying to cut what I spend on gas.

Comment: @jay - all good points, but if he grosses $100k and is living on $21k, I think finding places to save shouldn't be the top priority. The question can use some editing to add a larger context.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Sure. But if he makes $100k and spends $21k, I don't think finances are much of an issue for him at all, and he has no need to be on his site. The more common situation is surely someone who makes $21k and spends $100k.

Comment: Tremendously variable costs of living in different areas make this comparison fairly meaningless unless more precisely specified...

Answer (score 1):

Here are the numbers from 2007-2008

http://www.bls.gov/cex/anthology11/csxanth6.pdf

Comment: The Bureau of Labor Statistics constantly pleasantly surprises me (why give salary.com a buck when you can get the milk from the Occupational Outlook Quarterly for free?).  This is an exceptional document and to my eyes precisely what the OP asked about.